# How to get guava cache expire time left java?

Tags: java, spring, guava

I have created a cache object with this code. It is a google-guava cache.

```
Cache<String, String> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterAccess(7200, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

I need to get the expire time left. For example, after 3000 seconds, i want to get "there are 4200 seconds left to expire." Do you know any way about this?

I need to get the expire time left and i want to use this value.

Comment: Not sure if guava supports that. But you can always create your own class like `ValueWithTimestamp<String>` that holds a value and a timestamp when it was loaded into the cache. That way you can calculcate the time left yourself.

Comment: That's available in the successor project, [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). You can query using the `Cache.policy()` api, e.g. `ageOf(key)`.